# Clustering elements based on highest similarity

Tags: algorithm, docker, cluster-analysis, similarity

I'm working with Docker images which consist of a set of re-usable layers. Now given a collection of images, I would like to combine images which have a large amount of shared layers.

To be more exact: Given a collection of N images, I want to create clusters where all images in a cluster share more than X percent of services with eachother. Each image is only allowed to belong to one cluster.

My own research points in the direction of cluster algorithms where I use a similarity measure to decide which images belong in a cluster together. The similarity measure I know how to write. However, I'm having difficulty finding an exact algorithm or pseudo-algorithm to get started.

Can someone recommend an algorithm to solve this problem or provide pseudo-code please?

EDIT: after some more searching I believe I'm looking for something like this hierarchical clustering ( https://github.com/lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java ) but with a threshold X so that neighbors with less than X% similarity don't get combined and stay in a separate cluster.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by using hierarchical clustering and then traversing each branch of the dendrogram top to bottom until I find a cluster where the distance is below a threshold. Worst case there is no such cluster but then I'll end up in a leaf of the dendrogram which means that element is in a cluster of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by using hierarchical clustering and then traversing each branch of the dendrogram top to bottom until I find a cluster where the distance is below a threshold. Worst case there is no such cluster but then I'll end up in a leaf of the dendrogram which means that element is in a cluster of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a developer and you have no experience with data science?

There are a number of clustering algorithms and they have their advantages and disadvantages (please consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), but I think solution for your problem is easier than one can think.

I assume that N is small enough so you can store a matrix with N^2 float values in RAM memory? If this is the case, you are in a very comfortable situation. You write that you know how to implement similarity measure, so just calculate the measure for all N^2 pairs and store it in a matrix (it is a symmetric matrix, so only half of it can be stored). Please ensure that your similarity measure assigns special value for pair of images, where similarity measure is less than some X%, like 0 or infinity (it depends on that you treat a function like similarity measure or like a distance). I think perfect solution is to assign 1 for pairs, where similarity is greater than X% threshold and 0 otherwise.

After that, treat is just like a graph. Get first vertex and make, e.g., deep first search or any other graph walking routine. This is your first cluster. After that get first not visited vertex and repeat graph walking. Of course you can store graph as an adjacency list to save memory.

This algorithm assumes that you really do not pay attention to that how much images are similar and which pairs are more similar than other, but if they are similar enough (similarity measure is greater than a given threshold).

Unfortunately in cluster analysis it is common that 100% of possible pairs has to be computed. It is possible to save some number of distance calls using some fancy data structures for k-nearest neighbor search, but you have to assure that your similarity measure hold triangle inequality.

If you are not satisfied with this answer, please specify more details of your problem and read about:

K-means (main disadvantage: you have to specify number of clusters)

Hierarchical clustering (slow computation time, at the top all images are in one cluster, you have to cut a dendrogram at proper distance)

Spectral clustering (for graphs, but I think it is too complicated for this easy problem)